# How to get send main in my mail account using codeigniter mailer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am using codeigniter for sending mail directly..
How to get send main in my mail account using codeigniter mailer?

my Code:

```
    $ci = get_instance();
        $ci->load->library('email');
        $config['useragent'] = "Codeigniter";
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.example.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "account@example.com"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "Password";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

        $ci->email->initialize($config);

        $ci->email->from('account@example.com', 'Account');
        $list = array($email);
        $ci->email->to($list);
        $this->email->reply_to('account@example.com', 'Account');
        $ci->email->subject('Verify your Email');
        $ci->email->message('Massge body contain');
        $ci->email->send();
```

I want to get all send email in account@example.com send mail box. it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add cc or bcc your email account better bcc

```
$this->email->cc('account@example');

or 

$this->email->bcc('account@example');
```